# Module import error even though sys.path shows the directory?

Tags: python, module, anaconda, opc

I am having trouble installing a package through its directory (not possible to install through pip, only folder available) on my mac.

I am using a python 2.7 environment on Conda and did the following after reading many posts and tutorials:

- decompressed the file with the modules I need ("/Users/personal/python_files/PyOPC-0.1/PyOPC")
- used the command `conda develop "path/to/PyOPC"` on the terminal
- added the following line to the bottom of the `~/.bash_profile` file: `export PYTHONPATH="/path/to/PyOPC"`
- checked my sys.path through `python2 -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"` on the terminal

When I do the latter, I can see the path to PyOPC listed there, so I thought I wouldn't have problems importing any modules.

Nonetheless, when I run my code I get the following:

```
from basic import BasicXDAServer
ImportError: No module named basic
```

basic.py is a file inside the folder `PyOPC/servers`. If I move "basic" to the main PyOPC folder, I get a different import error referring to an import happening within basic.py...

Here is the complete directory I am referring to available on Github: https://github.com/ibh-systems/pyopc/tree/master/PyOPC

Is there a problem with the structure of the directory itself or did I do something wrong as I installed it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: try: `from PyOPC.servers.basic import BasicXDAServer`. You've got `PyOPC` on your path, but that doesn't mean you've got the subdirectories of `PyOPC`. You need to specify the full import path starting from the base that is on your path.

Comment: I tried that and got a similar error: `"no module named PyOPC.servers.basic".` If I get rid of the subdirectories, I still get an import error, even though I have all the .py files available in the `PyOPC` directory.

Comment: @Macattack I have altered a few files and their import lines and seem to have stumbled on a even bigger issue: ``File "/Users/joaofaller/opt/anaconda3/envs/python_27_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hyperlink/_url.py", line 30, in <module> from typing import ( ImportError: No module named typing``. This seems to be a problem with Python 2.7 and the way this package was coded back then (~12 y ago). Should I just give up?

Comment: 1st, don't move files. However PyOPC is structured is how it should stay. so, basic.py should be at `PyOPC/servers/basic.py` 2nd, for typing, you'll need to install `typing` which is a builtin package in python 3.6+ but a separate package you have to install before then e.g. python2.7

Comment: @Macattack thanks for the help - I was able to solve the problem and now the code is running just fine. I did run into a different problem but nothing related to the posted question. Thanks!